# Why do I get the error Failed asserting that Response Object (...) is an instance of class "RedirectResponse"?

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit

**Issue**

PHPUnit assertion `$this->assertRedirectedToAction('CatsController@index')` fails.

**Route**

`Route::get('/','CatsController@index');`

**Test Case**

```
class CatTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testHomePageRedirection()
    {
        $this->call('GET','/');
        $this->assertRedirectedToAction('CatsController@index');

    }
```

**Error**

```
Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse".

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/AssertionsTrait.php:110
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crudapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/AssertionsTrait.php:140
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crudapp/app/tests/CatTest.php:13
```

Can someone help me identify why I'm running into this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not `redirected` to `CatsController@index` - that is the page you are on.

```
Route::get('/','CatsController@index')
Route::get('/redirect', function () {
     return Redirect::action('CatsController@index');
});

public function testHomePageOk()
{
    $this->call('GET','/');
    $this->assertResponseOk(); 
}


public function testRedirectToHomePage()
{
    $this->call('GET','/redirect');
    $this->assertRedirectedToAction('CatsController@index');
}
```

Comment: aha,I was wondering the same thing but waited for confirmation. Thanks.